# Is Glucose-6-phosphatase absent in all the 3 types of muscular tissues?

Tags: muscle, metabolism, glucose

While going through gluconeogenesis I came to know about Glucose-6-phosphatase. In my book it's stated that

> Glucose-6-phosphatase is mostly present in liver and kidney and is absent in muscles, brain and adipose tissue.

I want to be specific that whether it is true for all muscles or only 1 type of muscle.

Comment: Welcome to this community! Have you considered asking this on the Biology Stack Exchange?

Comment: Welcome. For others to learn what you are learning, could you please provide details of your textbook?

Answer (score 3):

In humans, glucose-6-phosphatase is actually a multiunit enzyme system (Hutton and O'Brien 2009. PMCID [2785553](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2785553/)). There are at least 3 [isoforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_isoform).

##### *G6PC*

The first isoform, encoded by the *G6PC* gene, is predominantly expressed in liver and kidney as is indicated in your textbook (Hutton and O'Brien 2009. PMCID [2785553](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2785553/)).

The most well studied function of glucose-6-phosphatase is in gluconeogenic tissues where it catalyzes the removal of phosphate to prepare the glucose molecule for transport outside of the cell.

[image]
<sup>Adapted from [this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glucose_6-phosphatase#/media/File:Alpha-D-glucopyranose_6-phosphate.svg) and [this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glucose_6-phosphatase#/media/File:Beta-D-Glucose.svg).</sup>

Although most gluconeogenesis occurs in the liver, some occurs in the kidneys (Clar *et al* 2014 PMCID [5678048](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5678048/)).

Patients with [biallelic](https://www.cancer.gov/publications/dictionaries/genetics-dictionary/def/biallelic) [pathogenic variants](https://www.cancer.gov/publications/dictionaries/genetics-dictionary/def/pathogenic-variant) of *G6PC* have [glycogen storage disease 1a](https://www.omim.org/entry/232200) which is characterized by severe hypoglycemia and hepatomegaly caused by the accumulation of glycogen.

##### *G6PC3*

The third isoform, encoded by the *G6PC3* gene, is the more broadly expressed. Some authors call it "the ubiquitously expressed glucose-6-phosphatase" (Martin *et al* 2002. PMID [12370122](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/12370122/)). The function of this isoform is more poorly understood. [Hutton and O'Brien](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2785553/) note that  some authors have theorized that

> the presence of *G6PC3* in muscle may explain the improvement in endogenous glucose production and the decrease in susceptibility to hypoglycemia in patients with GSD type 1a after puberty.

The [Human Protein Atlas](https://www.proteinatlas.org/ENSG00000141349-G6PC3/tissue) shows that *G6PC3* is expressed in cardiac, skeletal and smooth muscle.

[image]

I have been unable to find any expression datasets which compare fast and slow twitch skeletal muscle.

Patients with [biallelic](https://www.cancer.gov/publications/dictionaries/genetics-dictionary/def/biallelic) [pathogenic variants](https://www.cancer.gov/publications/dictionaries/genetics-dictionary/def/pathogenic-variant) of *G6PC3* have [Dursun syndrome](https://www.omim.org/entry/612541) which is characterized by neutropenia and cardiac abnormalities which demonstrates the effect outside of the liver and kidney.

##### Conclusions

Thus, your textbook is correct that the *G6PC* gene is largely expressed in the liver and kidney where is is involved in gluconeogenesis. However, other isoforms of glucose-6-phosphatase are expressed outside the kidney and liver, including in muscles.

The function of the second isoform, encoded by the *G6PC2* gene is more controversial, so I will leave it to the reader to explore more (Hutton and O'Brien 2009. PMCID [2785553](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2785553/)).

Comment: When referencing sources through superscript numbers, it may look neat in some respects, but the linking provided can be small and difficult to use on a mobile phone screen. Could you please provide a list of your numbers and references at the bottom of your answer? Not only then does this make navigation easier, it provides the information when printed (if anyone wished to do so).

Comment: Also, I feel that while simple definition linking is fine with just a direct link, if a link is provided to a journal article for example like your link to *"Some authors have theorized that"*, source information, I think, should be readily recognised and again viewable in printed form. [Just some friendly suggestions]

Comment: I think we are all biased towards our own fields when it comes to reference styles. You may prefer APA because you work in that field. I am primed to prefer this style because it minimizes the number of characters used so you can cram more information into that 12 page grant. To me, the reference list at the bottom is a bit messy. I can certainly see your points though. If [meta consensus is reached](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1325/is-there-a-preferred-referencing-style-to-use) (I upvoted that one weeks ago), I am more than willing to change my behavior.